# Finding out highest values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file in which I have two columns, first one is class name and the second one is lines of code. overall there are 568 rows in the file and I want to find out top 25 results with the highest number of lines of code and print them on a different sheet.

Comment: you can use a pivot table for this, and then filter on top N for top 25 lines etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Pivot Table.

Put the *Class Name* under "Rows" and *Lines of Code* under "Values".

Then filter the row labels by the *Value Filter* "Top 10..." but change "10" to "25".

[image: Top 10 Filter (Class)]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the large() function - the argument k is the the position you want returned so for the top 25 you need 25 cells with that function... Shown for one in the picture (the cell E4 shows the function entered in cell E5):
[image]